TypeError: Invalid Attempt To Destructure Non-Iterable Instance Error Message (React Navigation/Firebase Auth)
The entire error message is:

TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance. In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a symbol.iteratormethod

My App.js is as follows:
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { onAuthStateChanged, User } from 'firebase/auth';
import { useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import React from 'react';

import LoginScreen from './pages/LoginScreen';
import Welcome from './pages/Welcome';
import { FIREBASE_AUTH } from './FirebaseConfig';

 const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
 const InsideStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function AuthLayout () {
  return (
    <InsideStack.Navigator>
      <InsideStack.Screen
        name='Welcome'
        component={Welcome}
        options={{headerShown:false}}>
    </InsideStack.Screen>
    </InsideStack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {

  const [user, setUser] = useState <User | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(FIREBASE_AUTH, (user) => {
      setUser(user);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
     <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Login'>
        {user ?  
        <Stack.Screen
          name='Welcome'
          component={Welcome}
          options={{headerShown: false}}>      
       </Stack.Screen>
        :
       <Stack.Screen
          name='Login'
          component={LoginScreen}
          options={{headerShown:false}}>
       </Stack.Screen>  
      } 
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

I've tried taking the array out of the Use Effect line and wrapping the InsideLayout function in an array to no avail
